# AWS Architecture for Simple Monitoring Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, monitoring, iot

I am new to AWS and trying to figure out what services to use for the following purpose:
1) read open source data on wave, wind, currents from a govt website (ndbc) every 15mins
2) Apply transformation to this data to convert to a target variable (busing a trained regression model)
3) Plot the target variable time history and show it as a dashboard that can be monitored by the user

Can someone suggest what services would need to be used and what the basic architecture would look like?

Thanks,
SJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Lambda with a curl command using cloudwatch cron as a trigger storing in S3 2) Lambda from S3 to extract and process data to feed to Kinesis 3) Pull to Sagemaker for ML or pull to Redshift